# Batch convert Microsoft Word files to HTML files

Tags: microsoft-word, conversion, html, linux-server

How can Microsoft Word files (`.doc`, `.docx`) be converted to HTML files as a batch process running on a Linux server?

Comment: Can you use OpenOffice on that server?

Comment: @slhck: Yes I can.

Answer (score 3):

Install unoconv and put together a script, e.g:

```
for f in *.doc
do
    unoconv -f html $f
done
```